# Structure passing to MPI in C++

Tags: c++, mpi

I am trying to create a custom data type for MPI and pass the structure of d_type from the root process to other processes but I am getting a segmentation fault and the following error. I want to later make a vector of structure and then pass that vector from the root process to other processes.

Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key[blackbirdx-H170-Gaming-3:11787] *** Process received signal ***

[blackbirdx-H170-Gaming-3:11787] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)

[blackbirdx-H170-Gaming-3:11787] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)

[blackbirdx-H170-Gaming-3:11787] Failing at address: 0x7ffd2daa9dd8

[blackbirdx-H170-Gaming-3:11788] *** Process received signal ***

[blackbirdx-H170-Gaming-3:11789] *** Process received signal ***

[blackbirdx-H170-Gaming-3:11789] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)

[blackbirdx-H170-Gaming-3:11789] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)

[blackbirdx-H170-Gaming-3:11789] Failing at address: 0x7ffd2daa9dd8

```
#include <iostream>
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#include <mpi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>  
#include <chrono> 
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct d_type{
    string timestamp;
    int lightpostID;
    int carTraffic;
};
class trafficData
{
public:
    string timestamp;
    int lightpostID;
    int carTraffic;

    trafficData(string timestamp, int lightpostID, int carTraffic);
};

trafficData::trafficData(string timestamp, int lightpostID, int carTraffic)
{
    this->timestamp = timestamp;
    this->lightpostID = lightpostID;
    this->carTraffic = carTraffic;
}
#define TRAFFIC_LIGHTS 5 
#define SIMULATION_TIME 3
#define MASTER_RANK 0
MPI_Status status;
#define CLASS_MASTER 1
#define CLASS_WORKER 2
int counter =0;
void generateTraffic();
// Read into queue.
void dataProducer();
// Read data from queue and sort it into list.
void dataConsume();
queue<trafficData> dataQueue;
vector<trafficData> sortedTraffic;
vector<trafficData> hourlyTraffic;
vector<string> movementLog;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sizeCommunicator,rankProcess,idProcess,offsetTotal;
    int offsetRow,workProcess,remainder,whole_part;
    int message_tag;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &sizeCommunicator);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rankProcess);
    if(sizeCommunicator < 2){
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
    }
    MPI_Datatype string_dt;
    MPI_Type_contiguous(6, MPI_CHAR, &string_dt);
    MPI_Type_commit(&string_dt);
    
    MPI_Datatype traffic_type;
    const int nitems=3;
    int blocklengths[nitems] = {1,1,1};
    const MPI_Aint displacements[nitems] = { offsetof(d_type, timestamp), offsetof(d_type, lightpostID), offsetof(d_type, carTraffic) };
    MPI_Datatype types[nitems] = {  string_dt ,MPI_INT, MPI_INT};
    MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems, blocklengths, displacements, types, &traffic_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&traffic_type);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(rankProcess == MASTER_RANK) {
        workProcess = sizeCommunicator - 1;
        string str="11:55";
        d_type buffer;
        buffer.timestamp="11:00";
        buffer.lightpostID=1;
        buffer.carTraffic=500;
    
        message_tag = CLASS_MASTER;
            for(idProcess = 1; idProcess <= workProcess; idProcess ++ ){
              MPI_Send(&buffer, 1, traffic_type, idProcess, message_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            }
        message_tag = CLASS_WORKER;
            for(idProcess = 1; idProcess <= workProcess; idProcess ++){
                MPI_Recv(&str[0], 1, string_dt, idProcess, message_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                cout<<str<<endl;
            }
    }
    if(rankProcess != MASTER_RANK){
        string str;
        d_type data;
        message_tag = CLASS_MASTER;
        MPI_Recv(&data, 1, traffic_type, MASTER_RANK, message_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        
       //cout<<data.timestamp<<endl;
        // cout<<str<<endl;
        str="gone";
        message_tag = CLASS_WORKER;
        MPI_Send(&str[0], 1, string_dt, MASTER_RANK, message_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not used `MPI`, but where is the indication that it can work with types that are non-POD and/or not trivially-copyable?  Your `struct` has `std::string` as member variables, thus making them non-POD and not trivially copyable.  I would think that you need to use `C` layout-compatible structs.

Comment: you cannot use `std::string` and build your derived datatype as if it was a `char[6]`

Comment: Consider using Boost.MPI to pass C++ data types. MPI itself has only C API which knows nothing about classes.

Comment: `std::string` is a struct itself containing a pointer to the heap. There is no way to define a single MPI derived datatype that works with many instances of `std::string` because the heap pointer is different in each instance.